# What is a proxy forwarding server called?

Tags: networking, proxy, forwarding

I've been trying to know the answer but all the keywords I've used for Google search returned things that doesn't have relation to my question.

Currently, I call it `proxy forwarding server` but this is not its correct name.

So what I want to know its name is those proxy servers which forward their requests to a proxy list. The below example will illustrate it more:

1. A client does a HTTP request with the proxy `127.0.0.1:8888`
2. The proxy server `127.0.0.1:8888` (which I currently call `proxy forwarding server`) will get a random proxy from a list (for example `proxies.txt`)
3. The proxy server `127.0.0.1:8888` will forward the request sent by the client to the random proxy that got fetched from the list.

Examples of those: [this](https://gist.github.com/darkwave/52842722c0c451807df4) and [this](https://github.com/DKingCN/RPS) (both are coded in Python)

Answer (score 0):

> What is a proxy forwarding server called?

The most common terms would probably either be "gateway" or "forward proxy".

> I want to know the common name for proxy servers which forward their requests to a proxy list.

I think the key here is in your second link. Based on some Googling, these seem to be commonly called "Rotating Proxies" (though this seems to be used more in reference to the IP, where "IP" is arguably synonymous with "proxy").